# Cannot install or update packages with pacman (Arch Linux)

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

[image]

When I try to do `sudo pacman -Syu`, it gives me `error: config file /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist could not be read: No such file or directory`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restore a valid mirrorlist file from the original source:

```
$ sudo bash
# mkdir -p /etc/pacman.d
# curl -s "https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/?country=US&country=GB&protocol=https&use_mirror_status=on" | sed -e 's/^#Server/Server/' -e '/^#/d' > /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
# pacman -S archlinux-keyring
# pacman -Syu
# exit
$
```

The list you are getting is for some specific countries; here, US and GB are used. Feel free to enter your own country or countries close to you.

The commandline above is adapted from the original documentation at [the Archlinux Wiki page on Mirrors](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mirrors).  I have entered interactive mode in `sudo` to have correct rights for redirection and I have removed the sorting by mirror speeds because you may or may not have the script for sorting.

EDIT: If you get errors about non-existing mirror servers you can edit the file `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` and comment out those that do not work, e.g.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
===>
# comment out whole lines by hash like this:
#  Server = https://mirror.0x.sg/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = https://mirror.netweaver.uk/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
# Server = https://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
(...)
```

You can also create `Server` entries for that file by hand at [the Archlinux Pacman Mirrorlist Generator](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/).  Enable the "Use mirror status:" checkmark [X].

Comment: I followed this and when i run `pacman -Syu`, it gives me the error `error: could not register 'archlinuxcn' database (database already registered)
`

Comment: and 
`error: failed retrieving file 'archlinuxcn.db' from mirror.0x.sg : The requested URL returned error: 404
`

Comment: OK, please try US and GB as above, that ought to work.

Comment: and  `error: failed to update archlinuxcn (failed to retrieve some files)
` with `error: failed to synchronize all databases
` too, four errors

Comment: oh ok i'll try it

Comment: Also, I added instructions on how to comment out `Server` lines of servers that do not work.

Comment: Thanks Ned64 i fixed it

Comment: That's great, please accept and vote up if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue on the MSYS2 for the clang64 mirror list :

```bsh
mkdir clang64_repair && cd clang64_repair 

wget https://packages.msys2.org/package/pacman-mirrors?repo=msys&variant=x86_64
tar -I zstd -xvf ./pacman-mirrors-*.pkg.tar.zst
cp ./etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.clang64 /etc/pacman.d/.
pacman -Syy

cd .. && rm -r clang64_repair
```